# jQuery AJAX multi select per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following pseudo code for example: I want to use the same ajax script to select phone_type and method per record, I tried using .attr()

```js
<script>
   $('#phone_type').on('change', function (e) {
     console.log(e);
   
     var phone_type = e.target.value;
   
     //ajax
     $.get('../get_conversion_method_by_phone_type?phone_type=' + phone_type, function (data) {
       //success data
       $('#method').empty();
       $('#method').append('<option value="0" selected>Choose Method</option>');
       $.each(data, function (index, conMethObj) {
         $('#method').append('<option value="' + conMethObj.id + '">' + conMethObj.method + '</option>');
       });
     });      
   });
</script>
```

```html
foreach($foo as $bar){
<tr>
   <select id="phone_type" name="phone_type">
      <option>Choose</option>
   </select>
   <select id="method" name="method">
     
   </select>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: can you show the result you want to see. i didn`t understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I just have the same inputs per row, so I want to select and trigger the appropriate   #method per $bar.

Answer (score 2):

well i hope i understand correctly what you want to do, try this code

```js
<script>
   $('.phone_type').on('change', function (e) {
       console.log(e);
       var $self = $(this);
       var phone_type = e.target.value;
   
       //ajax
       $.get('../get_conversion_method_by_phone_type?phone_type=' + phone_type, function (data) {
           //success data
           $method = $self.next('.method');
           $method.empty();
           $method.append('<option value="0" selected>Choose Method</option>');
           $.each(data, function (index, conMethObj) {
              $method.append('<option value="' + conMethObj.id + '">' + conMethObj.method + '</option>');
   
           });
       });
   
   });
</script>
```

and the html

```js
foreach($foo as $bar){
<tr>
   <select class="phone_type" name="phone_type">
      <option>Choose</option>
   </select>
   <select class="method" name="method">
     
   </select>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: I am getting the data object but it is not appending on  <select class="method" name="method"> for some reason

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so i can see what you get?

Comment: difficult to reproduce, for:   $method = $self.next('.method');
                console.log($method); I get in the console:Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: <select#phone_type.form-control.phone_type>. besides that nothing

Comment: i create a jsfiddle and get it to work i get the $method length = 1 . https://jsfiddle.net/yde0zfh8/14/    please paste your html and send me back your link so i can figure what went wrong

Comment: the html is fine the issue is with  $.each(data, function (index, conMethObj) {  $method.append('<option value="' + conMethObj.id + '">' + conMethObj.method + '</option>');});